# how to fetch specific part of an html page into webBrowser control?

Tags: html, vb.net, dom, webbrowser-control

I am working on getting only a part of the navigated webpage.
for example, "the face book . com" homepage.
I only want the division of groups on the left to appear in my web Browser control.
is that possible?
I am having ideas on fetching  but i don't know how to do it. any other way is fine. 
also, please let me know where to put the code, because i am new on vb.net

```
web.Document.All("mConnect").InvokeMember("click")
```

this is for clicking something inside the html

```
web.Document.getElementId("<div>").InnerHtml("")
```

is this code correct? what is it for?
let's say we cut the google homepage 4 ways. and i only want  Quadrant 2 to appear in my webBrowser control. is that possible? I think this is a clearer explanation..

Comment: What have you tried (aka "show code") and where is your specific problem (aka "show code")?

Comment: If you simply need to display Facebook's status update field, Facebook probably has an API for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw one post in this forum that technically solved my problem by manually forcing the webbrowser control to scroll to what place I want.

```
Web.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(320,10,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

320 is the width, 10 is the height. edit to where you want it to be.
adjust the size of your webBrowser then you can particularly choose the part that you want to see, disable scrollbars if you want.